# How can I adress the parent menuItem in a nested dashboardSidebar

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the example below, there are two `menuItem`s (1 and 2) and a `menuSubItem` (2.1) thats nested within `menuItem` 2. Each `menuItem` has a corresponding `tabItem` with a `box`, where the boxtitle is the name of the menuItem. If i run this app "Menu 1" is initally selected and shows the `box` called "1". If i than click on "Menu 2" the `menuSubItem` expands, but the body does not change at all. 
I don't think that this is the normal behaviour, is there a way to fix this?

And a second question. If I have selected "Menu 2.1" and click on "Menu 1" why does the nested `menuItem` do not collapse again?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable=TRUE), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Menu 1",
        tabName="menu1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Menu 2",
        tabName = "menu2",
        menuSubItem(
          "Menu 2.1",
          tabName = "menu2_1"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="menu1",
              box("1")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName="menu2",
              box("2")
      ),       
      tabItem(tabName="menu2_1",
              box("2.1")
     )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you see is normal, see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html)

> - Childless menuItem()s/menuSubItem()s must be given a tabName argument
> - Childfull” menuItem()s cannot have a tabName or a selected argument
>     (or rather, they can, but this will be completely ignored by Shiny).
>     Instead, at most, one of them can take a  startExpanded = TRUE, which
>     tells Shiny to start out with that menuItem() expanded, i.e. revealing
>     all its children

You can access the expanded tab with my code below, so you can create behavior based on that, but I do not think it is possible to display a page when clicking a menuItem that has children.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable=TRUE), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Menu 1",
        tabName="menu1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Menu 2",
        expandedName = "menu2",
        menuItem(
          "Menu 2.1",
          tabName = "menu2_1"
        )
      )
    ),
    textOutput('selectedmenu')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="menu1",
              box("1")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName="menu2",
              box("2")
      ),       
      tabItem(tabName="menu2_1",
              box("2.1")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$selectedmenu <- renderText({
    print(input$sidebarItemExpanded)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Change first tab when menu 2 is expanded, request from comment:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable=TRUE), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="mysidebar",
      menuItem(
        "Menu 1",
        tabName="menu1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Menu 2",
        expandedName = "menu2",
        menuItem(
          "Menu 2.1",
          tabName = "menu2_1"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="menu1",
              box("1")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName="menu2",
              box("2")
      ),       
      tabItem(tabName="menu2_1",
              box("2.1")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
    updateTabItems(session,"mysidebar","menu2_1")
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Okay. I want the menuItems on start to be collapsed. But when I click on a childfull menuItem I want it to expand and change the mainframe.
Is there a way that one of the menuSubItems is selected directly when clicking on the parent frame?

Comment: I added code to my answer, I hope this does what you want. If you find my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, that helps, thank you. Do you have a suggestion to my second question? It is not that much of a Problem, but it looks strange that when I select a menuItem outside of the subItems, that the subItems do not collapse again